# Convert VMDK file to compressed RAW file

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vmdk

## Explanation:

I created one virtual machine on my computer with VMWare. Now I need to move it on a VPS in Frankfurt.

Using the function provided by VMWare I created a **snapshot** (VMDK file)

On the hosting website I must upload a **RAW** format file.

To do the conversion I used [qemu-img converter](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html). According to the website, I tried to convert the vmdk to raw using this command:

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw image.vmdk image.img
```

It works, but I obtained a largest file.

The **VMDK** image is **3.22GB** and the **RAW** image after the conversion is **56.3GB**

I have created the Virtual Machine with **60GB** of disk size, so if I understood correctly:

1. The **VMDK** file contains only the files that I created on the
   virtual machine.
2. The **RAW** file have this big disk size because it get the size
   that I had indicated during the VM creation.

If this two observation are right the third question make sense.

## Questions:

- Is possible to reduce the **RAW** image size **(compress it)**?
- I have to buy the **VPS**, but if I can't compress the RAW image, I have to buy it with 64GB of disk space?
- Could be an idea to resize the allocated disk to the Virtual Machine ( eg. **10GB**) and export it again as **VMDK** and after that convert to **RAW**?

**EDIT 01/10/18**:

After a lots of tests I figured out that is not possible to shrink the virtual disk size, the best solution is to create another **VM** with smaller disk and copy all the data on it (using rsync). If for you is important to not lost users, ssh ftp configuration etc.. I don't know how to do that. I have created again all the configuration.

I have tryed to convert in different format, VDI, HDD, RAW and reduce the virtual disk size is not possible on all the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to convert VMDK to VHD if the VMDK is just a simple/single partition/volume. If VMDK contains multiple partitions many tools will fail during conversion.

If it's convertable to VHD then Windows has disk management to shrink disks/partitions.

You could use this to shrink the VHD and then perhaps convert it back to VMDK.

I checked there is an option available: "shrink volume".

This might just be the thing you are looking for.